# How can I define a Hebrew/Latin layout + Compose Key in Mageia 2?

Tags: linux, keyboard, xorg, mandriva

I'm on Mageia Linux Cauldron (what will become Mageia 2), where Mageia Linux is a recent community fork of Mandriva Linux.

This script gives me the Xkb layout that I need:

```
#!/bin/sh

setxkbmap \
    -option "" \
    -option "compose:ralt,grp:switch,grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"  \
    -variant ",lyx" \
    'us,il'
```

Now, I have this in /etc/sysconfig/keyboard:

```
XkbModel=pc105
XkbLayout=us,il
KEYBOARD=il
KEYTABLE=us
XkbOptions=compose:ralt,grp:switch,grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll
```

But the compose key is not configured using this by default (on X startup).

I used to be able to define the keyboard layout using directives in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` but it no longer appears to work.

How can I define everything I need by editing `/etc/sysconfig/keyboard` (or any other appropriate files under `/etc`)? I'm looking for a solution that will be system-wide, permanent, and cross-desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Replying to myself, I'd like to say that I found a good way to do that. Just define a file called ".Xkbmap" under the home directory with contents such as:

```
-option compose:ralt,grp:switch,grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll  -variant ,lyx us,il
```

And your current user should be good to go.

Thanks to everybody who tried to help.